# Configure PollyJS to ignore some requests

Tags: node.js, jestjs, pollyjs

I'm using PollyJS to record network requests in my tests. It works well when the only network request is the one that I want recorded - e.g. to an external service.

I'm now trying to do an integration test where my jest code spins up a local server running on the ubiquitous 127.0.0.1:3000 and that server makes a call to an external service.

So my test does a `GET` to `http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/some-path` and that route makes a call to `http://example.com/some-path`. I want PollyJS to ignore the request to `127.0.0.1:3000` and do the usual interception and recording for the latter. How do I configure it to do that?

I've been reading and experimenting with the settings in the [config docs](https://github.com/Netflix/pollyjs/blob/master/docs/configuration.md) but no luck so far.

Comment: Was looking for something like Polly recently but didn't find it for some reason despite its popularity, glad you mentioned it. Please, specify the code where exactly you run a server in tests and how requests to remote API are done. That you run it on 3000 for all tests altogether likely means that the server is started in another process, it will be impossible to intercept calls made inside the server in test processes.

Comment: Jest provides a JEST_WORKER_ID value that allows one to adjust the port so that each test suite does not clash with the other. This allows you to spin up a different server for each test suite in the same context/memory-space on a unique port and intercept calls to that (if needed) and still run the test in parallel. I use node-fetch to make these API calls. There's nothing special about the way that I do this.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that what I needed was `passthrough()`.

For example:

```js
polly.server.get(`<route-pattern>`).passthrough();
```

[Docs](https://netflix.github.io/pollyjs/#/server/overview)